# How to read and change variabled inside main form from another opened form?

Tags: c++, windows, forms, variables

When I have two forms (for example 'FormMain' and 'FormSettings') with the following code:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <string>
#include "FormMain.h"
#include "FormSettings.h"

using namespace std;

string someVariable = "";

void openFormSettings() {
    FormSettings myForm;
    myForm.ShowDialog();
}
```

I have opened 'FormMain' then I have opened the form 'FormSettings'. How do I read and make changes in the variable 'someVariable' from the second form I opened? This is variable is used to hold some setttings of the main form which could be changed in the settings form.

This could be a stupid question but I'm a beginner to C++ ...

Comment: You are not writing C++ code, the language is called C++/CLI.  Particularly the `#include <string>` directive doesn't do what you think it does.  This kind of trial and error is inevitably mostly error, visit your local library or bookstore and check out a book about Winforms programming.

Comment: You should tell us where in the `FormSettings` the user is supposed to type the text in ... There's probably a "text edit" or similar control that you put there ...

Comment: The user could change text in a windows form textbox and in a checkbox. Thats everything, then wenn the user presses OK the variables in the main form needs to be changed to the chages the user made. I hope you understand this, it is a bit hard to explain for me since I'm only 15 years old :$ and dutch. I'm sure this thing I wanted to have is really simple but I only need to know HOW I need to do this. Thanks

Comment: @HansPassant Do you say this is c++/CLI because I didn't paste the namespace, the public and private and  that kind of features in here, thats right I do have them but I didn't paste it in here just as a short example code :)

Comment: Does anyone have a solution yet, I really need it :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I think -- without knowing lots of details -- a possible strategy would be to construct the FormSettings so that it receives the FormMain as a reference (or a pointer), say you name it `formMain`. Then you can call `formMain.set_setting(blah);` in the button callback of FormSettings.